# Stop angular ui-router from reloading state's template and controller, if only params change?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have state defined like:

```
.state("root.home.foo", {
   url: "/foo/:id",
   templateUrl: "/static/partials/home.foo.html",
   controller: 'FooCtrl'
})
```

When in that state, I respond to a mouse click, wanting to change the parameter...

```
$state.go('root.home.foo', { id: newId });
```

But I'm getting flicker as it reloads the state's template and re-create's the controller. Can I make it so that the controller is not recreated?  It can respond to a `$stateChangeSuccess` event, and that's all I need.

**Update**

Following Jason's suggestion, I tried a sub-state. It works.

```
.state("root.home.foo", {
   abstract: true,
   url: "/foo",
   templateUrl: "/static/partials/home.foo.html",
   controller: 'FooCtrl'
})
.state("root.home.foo.itemSelected", {        
   url: "/:foo"
})
```

Listening to the `$stateChangeSuccess` event...

```
// In controller's constructor
$scope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function (e, to, toParams, from, fromParams) {
  if ($state.current.name == 'root.home.foo.itemSelected') {       
    handleSelection(toParams.id);
  }
});
```

Comment: Can you nest a state below it? "root.home.foo.stuffThatChangesWithId" Then only the 'stuff that changes with the id' would have to 'flicker', which since it's changing, probably will anyway.  You can even use named ui-views if it's scattered locations.

Comment: Another thought. As a workaround, would it work to make a manual change to the address using $location service and separately change your params manually to keep em all sync'd? I'm not sure if that would trigger the stateChange or not.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that first suggestion and update later.

Comment: also add in $state property - reloadOnSearch: false - after definition of controller.

Comment: Could you please post the solution as an answer and mark this question answered? This way users (like me) can easier find the solution

Answer (score 1):

Try setting `reloadOnSearch: false` in the route definition. E.g:

```
.state("root.home.foo", {
  url: "/foo/:id",
  templateUrl: "/static/partials/home.foo.html",
  controller: 'FooCtrl',
  reloadOnSearch: false
})
```